# How to use ternary operator for checkbox in haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, ternary-operator

I am confused about how to use the haml syntax for ternary operator to check if a checkbox is checked or not. I have a color_id column which stores values based on which checkbox is checked. Below is my code:

```
  .dress_color
    .form-group
    .checkbox.checkbox-primary.color_id
     = f.check_box :color_id, {}
     %label= t('.dark color')

    - if f.object.long_dress_selected?
          ...............
    - else
      = f.check_box, checked: true ? ('color_id: black') : ('color_id: white')
```

I want to check whether the 'dark_color' check box is checked or not, in the else part of the if-else condition. That is, if the checkbox is checked, color_id should be set to 'black' else it should be set to 'white'. 
But the above code is showing error as:

```
SyntaxError -html.haml:19: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
_false(( f.check_box, checked: true ? ('color_id
                              ^:
```

How to check the whether the checkbox is checked or not by using ternary operator?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I tried the syntax

> > f.check_box(color_id:, {}, checked_value ="black", unchecked_value = "white")

But it gave error as:

```
syntax error, unexpected ','
x(color_id:, {}, checked_value = "black", unch
           ^
file1.html.haml:40: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting tSTRING_DEND
));}\n", 0, false);end;_hamlout.
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with haml. It is about plain Ruby.

Comment: I am sorry if I am missing something obvious here but i tried almost everything in my knowledge but it is not working. any help will appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`check_box(method, options = {}, checked_value = "1", unchecked_value = "0")`**

Returns a checkbox tag tailored for accessing a specified attribute, Additional options on the input tag can be passed as a hash with options. The checked_value defaults to 1 while the default unchecked_value is set to 0 which is convenient for boolean values.

in your case

```
f.check_box(color_id:, {}, checked_value ="black", uchhecked_value = "white")
```

Refer the rails docs link [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-check_box)

Comment: Hey I tried the syntax but it gave the error. The error is as edited in the question

Comment: `can you try f.check_box("color_id", {}, checked_value ="black", uchhecked_value = "white")' color_id will be the attribute in the object

Comment: I tried f.check_box(:color_id, {}, checked_value = "black", unchecked_value = "white").But it is still taking the unchecked_value. What I want is, if the checkbox is checked, then a specific value should be stored else if not checked, a different value should be stored

Comment: can you comment the rendered html for the checkbox

Comment: It is not rendering a new page or anything. But the value needs to be stored in the DB